# XCode: Layering a button over the top of a custom UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uiview, xib

In XCode 11, I have a ViewController I'm using as the main page in a UI. In this VC there are six UIViews in two rows of three. Each UIView is customized using the same XIB, which provides formatting, a text string, and an image. All of this has worked great so far.

I would now like to add a button to each of the six UI Views. Each button will open a hyperlink using SFSafariViewController, using a URL which is unique to each button (i.e. there are six different hyperlinks which could be opened). I have attempted to do this three ways, but none are working out for me

1. Most preferred - I would like to add a button to the XIB file (myClass) with an IBAction function that is a method of myClass. I created a button on the XIB and linked it to the IBAction outlet below. I understand why this won't work - myClass is a subclass of UIView and "present" is a method of UIViewController - but I don't know what to write instead, or if it's possible

   ```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped() {
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!)
    present(vc,animated:true)}
   ```
2. Next best thing - in my main storyboard, I attempted to add a button to each UIView (so six total buttons). In storyboard, the button shows as sitting over the top of the UIView. But when the application runs, the button sits behind the UIView. Here is an image where I've colored the rounded-edge UIView white and the sharp-edge button green

[image: UIView appearing over button]

Help with either one of these solutions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try using delegation pattern, click one of button and delegate back to the main view controller to go to url?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately solved this issue with a solution to number 1 above, adding the button into the XIB. I referenced this video, with a caveat (see below):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBYdsYwoJVI&t

The short summary:

1. Create a XIB with your custom UIView, including the button you want to be included
2. Link the XIB to a Swift file, and create the button as an outlet in the file (myButton, in a file called myClass)
3. Switch back to your storyboard and set a UIView so that it becomes a myClass type
4. Create an outlet in the primary ViewController for this UIView (myView:myClass)

**This is the point at which I was stuck, and the point at which I wrote my question above**

5. In XCode, you can use the ViewController to assign a button a touch action, with the following code, where the function I am calling is named "buttonTap":

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   myView.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTap), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
   }
   ```
6. **Slightly different than the video**, then you just write your function outside of the viewDidLoad function - but make sure to make it visible to @objc if you are working in Swift 4.0 or later

   ```
   @objc func buttonTap(sender: UIButton){
   [button action]
   }
   ```